# A seemingly simple property of complex numbers that won't submit.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $|b-a|>|b|$ and $|a|>|b|$.  I want to show that the absolute value of the real part of $\frac{a}{b}$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.

For example, let $a=4+4i$ and $b=3i$.  Then they satisfy the property $|b-a|>|b|$, and $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{4}{3}i$. The real part is clearly greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.

I have attempted many different techniques, some basic, some complicated, but to no avail.  A geometric interpretation of the complex numbers seems potentially fruitful, but alas, I have had no luck there.

Comment: Shoot!  I forgot my running assumption that $|a|>|b|$, which is violated by the examples below.  I have made the change in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated form of the question is still not true; as the other answers have alluded to, if you make the substitution $z = a/b$, it is equivalent to assert that, for $z \in \mathbb Q(i)$, if $|1-z|>1$ and $|z|>1$, then the absolute value of the real part of $z$ is greater than $1/2$.

For a counterexample, simply choose $z$ with large imaginary part; e.g. take $z = 2i$, then $1-z = 1-2i$ has absolute value $\sqrt 5>1$. To put this back in terms of $a$ and $b$, simply take $b=1$ and $a=2i$.

Responding to "A geometric interpretation of the complex numbers seems potentially fruitful, but alas, I have had no luck there": $|z|>1$ says that $z$ does not lie in the closed unit disk around $0$. $|1-z|>1$ says that $z$ does not lie in the closed unit disk around $1$. $|\mathfrak{Re}(z)|>1/2$ says that $z$ does not lie in the vertical strip between real part $-1/2$ and real part $1/2$ (assuming you're viewing the complex plane with a horizontal real axis and a verticle imaginary axis). Clearly there are points in that last strip which lie outside the two disks specified in the first two conditions.

Comment: This is a clear counterexample to my claim, which tells me that there is more structure than I am seeing.  I.e., there must be some additional condition that I am satisfying without realizing it.  This example gets me out of the "all of my examples work" rut!  I'll have to figure out what else is going on that is giving my conclusion.  Thanks.

Comment: @Trevor Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Let $a=i$. Let $b=1$. Then $\sqrt{2}>1$ but $\frac{a}{b}=i$.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is equivalent to $|1-\frac ab|>1$. This can hardly exclude $|\Re\frac ab|<\frac12$. For example, let $a=-1$, $b=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$a = 1 + \frac12 i \\ b = 1-i$$
Then
$$
b-a = -\frac32 i \\ |b-a| = \frac32 \\ |b-a| > |b| = \sqrt{2}
$$
so $(a,b$ meets your conditions. But
$$
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{(1+\frac12 i)(1+i) }{(1-i)(1+i)} = \frac14 + \frac34 i \\
Re\left( \frac{a}{b} \right) = \frac14 < \frac 12
$$

Your conjecture is false.

Comment: The complex numbers have integral components, though, so this isn't a counterexample.